# MySql: Displaying Sums of all rows for each column as an extra row at the end

Tags: mysql

How do I get the sum of each column for all rows of a result-set? I mean I want to display the sums-row as the last row of my result-set.

My query looks like this:

```
select f.filename,  
count(distinct case when v.rUser like '%bike%' then 1 else null end) as bikeUser, 
count(distinct case when v.rUser like '%Pedestrian%' then 1 else null end) as pedestrianUser,  
count(distinct case when d.weather like '%clear%' then 1 else null end) as clearWeather, 
count(case when m.extras like '%hat%' then 1 else null end) as hatExtras 
from VMdata v  
inner join files f on v.id = f.id 
inner join DMdata d on f.id = d.id 
inner join MultiFiledata m on f.id = m.id 
where f.filename in (X,Y,Z) group by f.filename;
```

When I use **with roll up** after the 'group by' clause, it gives me sum of the groups generated by the 'group by clause' (horizontal sum) whereas I need the vertical sum of each column at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to post on http://sqlfiddle.com, I notice SQL problems has a higher chance of being solved if other developers can play with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ROLLUP is already correct, it's really the `COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Blah' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is the main culprit why your query is not working

You must do either:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Blah' THEN 1 END)
```

or

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Field = 'Blah' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

But since MySQL has a duality between boolean and integer type like it is in C language, hence you can do this too:

```
SUM(Field = 'Blah')
```

This is your incorrect query (wrong results): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70187/1

```
create table ProductInventory(
  ProductCode varchar(10) not null,
  Location varchar(50) not null
);


insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('CPU','US');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('CPU','US');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('CPU','CN');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('KB','CN');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('KB','JP');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('KB','US');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('MOUSE','US');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('MOUSE','CN');
```

Incorrect Output:

```
PRODUCTCODE USQTY   CHINAQTY
CPU         3       3
KB          3       3
MOUSE       2       2
            8       8
```

This is the correct query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70187/2

```
select ProductCode, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1 END) as UsQty,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'CN' THEN 1 END) as ChinaQty
from ProductInventory
group by ProductCode with rollup
```

Correct output:

```
PRODUCTCODE     USQTY   CHINAQTY
CPU             2       1
KB              1       1
MOUSE           1       1
                4       3
```

Please, don't insist that this is correct, this is **very incorrect**:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UsQty
```

You must either do this (correct) :

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1 END) AS UsQty
```

Or this (correct) : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70187/5

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UsQty
```

Or this (correct) : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70187/6

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1 END) AS UsQty
```

Or try take advantage of the fact that MySql has duality between boolean and integer (correct) : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70187/4

```
SUM(Location = 'US') AS UsQty
```

---

**Bottomline**

Please don't use this (incorrect) : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70187/3

```
COUNT(Location = 'US') as UsQty
```

And please don't use this too (incorrect, similar to your query): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70187/1

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as UsQty
```

---

By the way, this also works, it's for you to find out why ;-)

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1976 END) AS UsQty
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have an inkling that this is what you need:

```
create table Product
(
  ProductCode varchar(10) not null primary key,
  ProductName varchar(100) not null 
);


insert into Product(ProductCode,ProductName) values
('CPU','Central Processing Unit'),
('KB','Keyboard'),
('MSE','Mouse'),
('RAM', 'Random Access Memory');


create table ProductInventory(
  ProductCode varchar(10) not null,
  Location varchar(50) not null
);


insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values
('CPU','US'),
('CPU','PH'),
('CPU','PH'),
('KB','PH'),
('KB','US'),
('KB','US'),
('MSE','US'),
('MSE','JP');

select p.ProductCode, 
    coalesce(SUM(i.Location = 'US'),0) as UsQty,
    coalesce(SUM(i.Location = 'PH'),0) as PhilippinesQty
from Product p
left join ProductInventory i on i.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
group by p.ProductCode with rollup
```

Output:

```
ProductCode     UsQty           PhilippinesQty
CPU             1               2
KB              2               1
MSE             1               0
RAM             0               0
                4               4
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb09/1

Comment: This is great, really. I totally understood the whole concept. Thanks! But the fact is I'm using this 'Distinct' as well inside some of the count/sum functions (due to the fact that 'some' of the tables in the joins have one-to-many relationship), I've updated the query in my post above as well. 
So the columns without 'distinct' have correct total at the end, whereas first three columns with 'distinct' keyword have incorrect total. I have tried your different suggestions!

Comment: Hmm.. if you use `count(distinct case ConditionHere then 1 else 0 end)`, COUNT will have two kind of values only, that is, it's either 2 or 1, nothing else, isn't it? Maybe, I'm out of my depth today, but I cannot really see why there's a need for DISTINCT, and also the ELSE part

Comment: Yeah, with 'Distinct' its either 1 or 0 for each row, which is true...and if I don't put the else part then the resulting rows have only 1 or empty (but a 0 is required by my client instead of empty cells) I hope you got it....The reason of using **Distinct** will be clear to you if you read my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284872/mysql-using-case-when-then-end-for-multiple-inner-join-tables

Comment: "if I don't put the else part then the resulting rows have only 1 or empty (but a 0 is required by my client instead of empty cells)" <-- If by empty cells you mean `NULL` values; rest assured, NULL will never propagate to aggregate functions(`SUM`,`COUNT`,etc) that uses `INNER JOIN`, NULL can only propagate to `LEFT JOIN`, and if you happen to have NULL on aggregate results, you don't put the empty/NULL handling(your `ELSE` part) to inside of aggregate function, you put it outside of it, and you use `COALESCE( SUM(v.User LIKE '%bike%'), 0) AS BikeUser` instead of `ELSE`

Comment: in short, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` combo, see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb09/1 Really, `COUNT(case when expr then 1 else 0 end)` is very wrong on many fronts. Think about the non-matching row from Product 'RAM' to ProductInventory, 'RAM' has no corresponding inventory, analyze how you can convert the NULL(empty) to 0(required by your client)

Comment: Based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10285084 You need to use this: `Count(distinct case when [logic goes here] then [user ID] else null end) as bikeuser`, i.e. `count(distinct case when v.User LIKE '%bike%' then v.User else null end)`, to simplify, remove the superfluous `ELSE NULL`, use this: `coalesce(count(distinct case when v.User LIKE '%bike%' then v.User end), 0) as bikeUser`. For the love of our craft, never use `ELSE 0` on `COUNT`, it's very wrong, I can't emphasize it enough. When doing LEFT JOIN,use COALESCE around COUNT,SUM,etc to convert `NULL` to 0

Comment: Another puzzle, example, if information_schema.tables has 38 rows, what's the result of: `select count(case when 'HA' = 'HA' then 0 end) from information_schema.tables` ? If you are not sure of your answer, see this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c526/1

Comment: If you insist `ELSE 0` on `COUNT` aggregate, you might as well substitute your birthday on that `ELSE` part, it "works" the same anyway :-) This take the cake: `select count(case when 'blah' = 'bleh' then 1 else 'April 20, 1889' end) from information_schema.tables` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31559/1 –

Comment: Yeah, actually I was using NULL with the Else part, and I guess thats why I was getting the correct results. But thanks for explaining this Coalesce function. I will use this!

Comment: But my original issue still remains unresolved....in the "Summary Row" ( generated by **with rollup**), columns coming from **one-to-many** relationship tables are giving correct grand-sum, whereas columns coming from **one-to-one** relationship tables are giving incorrect grand-sum which is either 0 or 1 (note that all the values in these "one-to-one" columns are also either 0 or 1, which is correct).

Comment: Put in to your question some sample data say 15 to 20 rows, and include your desired output, it's guaranteed to make everyone attempt to provide solution to your problem. Take effort on that ;-)

Comment: Give people something to visualize on. Put in some sample data and the desired output based on that data. Visualization states the problem aloud, which in turn is an aid for [rubber duck debugging](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html). That way, people can easily solve your problem; who knows, you might be able to solve it yourself :-)

Comment: Can you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431660/mysql-multiple-left-join-giving-wrong-output)? Problem is clearer there!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use COUNT for counting when you are using evaluation; despite the name, SUM would yield the correct result for counting based on conditions:

Given this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79375/1

```
create table ProductInventory(
  ProductCode varchar(10) not null,
  Location varchar(50) not null
);


insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('CPU','US');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('CPU','US');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('CPU','ARM');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('KB','CN');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('KB','PH');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('KB','US');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('MOUSE','AA');
insert into ProductInventory(ProductCode,Location) values('MOUSE','BB');

select ProductCode, COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Qty
from ProductInventory
group by ProductCode
order by ProductCode
```

That will produce incorrect results:

```
PRODUCTCODE QTY
CPU         3
KB          3
MOUSE       2
```

Use SUM instead, correct results: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79375/3

```
select ProductCode, SUM(Location = 'US') as Qty
from ProductInventory
group by ProductCode
order by ProductCode
```

That would result to:

```
PRODUCTCODE QTY
CPU         2
KB          1
MOUSE       0
```

COUNT works by counting the NON-nullness of value or expression

---

If you still want to use COUNT, pass any non-null value to `COUNT`; and don't use `ELSE NULL END`, your query will look tedious, just saying :-) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79375/4

```
select ProductCode, COUNT(CASE WHEN Location = 'US' THEN Location END) as Qty
from ProductInventory
group by ProductCode
order by ProductCode
```

Output:

```
PRODUCTCODE QTY
CPU         2
KB          1
MOUSE       0
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation (although it was not relevent to my original question ;-) I think I will stick with the COUNT version (I tried both n they were giving the same results)...
But my real question still remains unanswered.

Comment: Hahah true this answer didn't answer your question. I just want to share the COUNT expression pitfall, doesn't fit on comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temptable (#mytemptable) and add the sum as last entry and then return the select of the created temptable. But this is only working in stored procedures I think.

```
select f.filename,  
count(case when v.rUser like '%bike%' then 1 else 0 end) as bikeUser, 
count(case when v.rUser like '%Pedestrian%' then 1 else 0 end) as pedestrianUser,  
count(case when d.weather like '%clear%' then 1 else 0 end) as clearWeather, 
count(case when m.extras like '%hat%' then 1 else 0 end) as hatExtras 
INTO #myTempTable from VMdata v  
inner join files f on v.id = f.id 
inner join DMdata d on f.id = d.id 
inner join MultiFiledata m on f.id = m.id 
where f.filename in (X,Y,Z) group by f.filename; 

INSERT INTO #myTempTable select(create the sum here but care that you have the same columns)

SELECT * FROM #myTempTable
```

within just one select you can do it with the command "UNION"

***EDITED: 27.04. 11:55**

```
select f.filename,  
count(case when v.rUser like '%bike%' then 1 else 0 end) as bikeUser, 
count(case when v.rUser like '%Pedestrian%' then 1 else 0 end) as pedestrianUser,  
count(case when d.weather like '%clear%' then 1 else 0 end) as clearWeather, 
count(case when m.extras like '%hat%' then 1 else 0 end) as hatExtras 
from VMdata v  
inner join files f on v.id = f.id 
inner join DMdata d on f.id = d.id 
inner join MultiFiledata m on f.id = m.id 
where f.filename in (X,Y,Z) group by f.filename;
UNION
SELECT SUM(bikeUser), SUM(pedestrianUser), SUM(clearWeather), SUM(hatExtras)
FROM (
select f.filename,  
count(case when v.rUser like '%bike%' then 1 else 0 end) as bikeUser, 
count(case when v.rUser like '%Pedestrian%' then 1 else 0 end) as pedestrianUser,  
count(case when d.weather like '%clear%' then 1 else 0 end) as clearWeather, 
count(case when m.extras like '%hat%' then 1 else 0 end) as hatExtras 
from VMdata v  
inner join files f on v.id = f.id 
inner join DMdata d on f.id = d.id 
inner join MultiFiledata m on f.id = m.id 
where f.filename in (X,Y,Z) group by f.filename) as summary
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: With your "UNION" suggestion, in the Second Select do I need to write the whole query(first select) again to get the sums from it?

Comment: I edited my post. Please try my second select (with union). But Iam not sure if its working, I just created it in my head (did not tried to execute it). maybe some syntaxerrors are included.

Comment: @noonecares no need to use UNION, MySQL has ROLLUP capability http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79375/15