# MySql: Multiple Left Join giving wrong output

Tags: mysql

I'm having a little trouble about using multiple Left Joins in a query. Some of the tables have one-to-one relationship with the left-table and some have one-to-many relation. The query looks like this:

```
Select 
    files.filename,
    coalesce(count(distinct case
                when dm_data.weather like '%clear%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as clear,
    coalesce(count(distinct case
                when dm_data.weather like '%lightRain%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as lightRain,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kc_data.type like '%bicycle%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as bicycle,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kc_data.type like '%bus%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as bus,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kpo_data.movement like '%walking%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as walking,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kpo_data.type like '%pedestrian%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as pedestrian
from
    files
        left join
    dm_data ON dm_data.id = files.id
        left join
    kc_data ON kc_data.id = files.id
        left join
    kpo_data ON kpo_data.id = files.id
where
    files.filename in (X, Y, Z, ........)
group by files.filename;
```

Here, dm_data table has a one-to-one relation with 'files' table (thats why I'm using 'Distinct'), whereas kc_data and kpo_data data has one-to-many relationship with the 'files' table. (kc_data and kpo_data can have 10 to 20 rows against one files.id). This query works fine.

The problem arises when I add another left join with another one-to-many table pd_markings (which can have 100s of rows against one files.id).

```
Select 
    files.filename,
    coalesce(count(distinct case
                when dm_data.weather like '%clear%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as clear,
    coalesce(count(distinct case
                when dm_data.weather like '%lightRain%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as lightRain,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kc_data.type like '%bicycle%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as bicycle,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kc_data.type like '%bus%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as bus,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kpo_data.movement like '%walking%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as walking,
    coalesce(count(case
                when kpo_data.type like '%pedestrian%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as pedestrian,
    **coalesce(count(case
                when pd_markings.movement like '%walking%' then 1
                    end),
            0) as walking**
from
    files
        left join
    dm_data ON dm_data.id = files.id
        left join
    kc_data ON kc_data.id = files.id
        left join
    kpo_data ON kpo_data.id = files.id
        left join
    **kpo_data ON pd_markings.id = files.id**
where
    files.filename in (X, Y, Z, ........)
group by files.filename;
```

Now all the values become multiple of each other. Any ideas???

Note that the first two columns return 1 or 0 value. Thats the desired result actually, as one-to-one relationship tables will only have either 1 or 0 rows against any files.id, so if I don't use 'Distinct' then the resulting value is wrong (i guess because of the other tables which are returning more then one row against same file.id) No, unfortunately, my tables don't have their own unique ID columns except the 'files' table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [flatten the results](http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/sql-count-computer-program-does-what.html) of your query, in order to obtain a right count.

You said you have one-to-many relationship from your files table to other table(s)

If SQL only has a keyword `LOOKUP` instead of cramming everything in `JOIN` keywords, it shall be easy to infer if the relation between table A and table B is one-to-one, using `JOIN` will automatically connotes one-to-many. I digress.  Anyway, I should have already inferred that your files is one-to-many against dm_data; and also, the files against kc_data is one-to-many too. `LEFT JOIN` is another hint that the relationship between first table and second table is one-to-many; this is not definitive though, some coders just write everything with `LEFT JOIN`. There's nothing wrong with your LEFT JOIN in your query, but if there are multiple one-to-many tables in your query, that will surely fail, your query will produce repeating rows against other rows.

```
from
    files
        left join
    dm_data ON dm_data.id = files.id
        left join
    kc_data ON kc_data.id = files.id
```

So with this knowledge that you indicate files is one-to-many against dm_data, and it is one-to-many also against kc_data. We can conclude that there's something wrong with chaining those joins and grouping them on one monolithic query.

An example if you have three tables, namely app(files), ios_app(dm_data), android_app(kc_data), and this is the data for example for ios:

```
test=# select * from ios_app order by app_code, date_released;
 ios_app_id | app_code | date_released | price  
------------+----------+---------------+--------
          1 | AB       | 2010-01-01    | 1.0000
          3 | AB       | 2010-01-03    | 3.0000
          4 | AB       | 2010-01-04    | 4.0000
          2 | TR       | 2010-01-02    | 2.0000
          5 | TR       | 2010-01-05    | 5.0000
(5 rows)
```

And this is the data for your android:

```
test=# select * from android_app order by app_code, date_released;
.android_app_id | app_code | date_released |  price  
----------------+----------+---------------+---------
              1 | AB       | 2010-01-06    |  6.0000
              2 | AB       | 2010-01-07    |  7.0000
              7 | MK       | 2010-01-07    |  7.0000
              3 | TR       | 2010-01-08    |  8.0000
              4 | TR       | 2010-01-09    |  9.0000
              5 | TR       | 2010-01-10    | 10.0000
              6 | TR       | 2010-01-11    | 11.0000
(7 rows)
```

If you merely use this query:

```
select x.app_code, 
    count(i.date_released) as ios_release_count, 
    count(a.date_released) as android_release_count
from app x
left join ios_app i on i.app_code = x.app_code
left join android_app a on a.app_code = x.app_code
group by x.app_code
order by x.app_code
```

The output will be wrong instead:

```
 app_code | ios_release_count | android_release_count 
----------+-------------------+-----------------------
 AB       |                 6 |                     6
 MK       |                 0 |                     1
 PM       |                 0 |                     0
 TR       |                 8 |                     8
(4 rows)
```

You can think of chained joins as cartesian product, so if you have 3 rows on first table, and has 2 rows on second table, the output will be 6

Here's the visualization, see that there is 2 repeating android AB for every ios AB. There are 3 ios AB, so what would be the count when you do COUNT(ios_app.date_released)? That will become 6; the same with `COUNT(android_app.date_released)`, this will also be 6. Likewise there's 4 repeating android TR for every ios TR, there are are 2 TR in ios, so that would give us a count of 8.

```
.app_code | ios_release_date | android_release_date 
----------+------------------+----------------------
 AB       | 2010-01-01       | 2010-01-06
 AB       | 2010-01-01       | 2010-01-07
 AB       | 2010-01-03       | 2010-01-06
 AB       | 2010-01-03       | 2010-01-07
 AB       | 2010-01-04       | 2010-01-06
 AB       | 2010-01-04       | 2010-01-07
 MK       |                  | 2010-01-07
 PM       |                  | 
 TR       | 2010-01-02       | 2010-01-08
 TR       | 2010-01-02       | 2010-01-09
 TR       | 2010-01-02       | 2010-01-10
 TR       | 2010-01-02       | 2010-01-11
 TR       | 2010-01-05       | 2010-01-08
 TR       | 2010-01-05       | 2010-01-09
 TR       | 2010-01-05       | 2010-01-10
 TR       | 2010-01-05       | 2010-01-11
(16 rows)
```

So what you should do is flatten each result before you join them to other tables and queries.

If your database is capable of CTE, please use so. It's very neat and very self-documenting:

```
with ios_app_release_count_list as
(
 select app_code, count(date_released) as ios_release_count
 from ios_app
 group by app_code
)
,android_release_count_list as
(
 select app_code, count(date_released) as android_release_count 
 from android_app 
 group by app_code  
)
select
 x.app_code, 
 coalesce(i.ios_release_count,0) as ios_release_count, 
 coalesce(a.android_release_count,0) as android_release_count
from app x
left join ios_app_release_count_list i on i.app_code = x.app_code
left join android_release_count_list a on a.app_code = x.app_code
order by x.app_code;
```

Whereas if your database has no CTE capability yet, like MySQL, you should do this instead:

```
select x.app_code, 
 coalesce(i.ios_release_count,0) as ios_release_count, 
 coalesce(a.android_release_count,0) as android_release_count
from app x
left join
(
 select app_code, count(date_released) as ios_release_count
 from ios_app
 group by app_code
) i on i.app_code = x.app_code
left join
(
 select app_code, count(date_released) as android_release_count 
 from android_app 
 group by app_code   
) a on a.app_code = x.app_code
order by x.app_code
```

That query and the CTE-style query will show the correct output:

```
 app_code | ios_release_count | android_release_count 
----------+-------------------+-----------------------
 AB       |                 3 |                     2
 MK       |                 0 |                     1
 PM       |                 0 |                     0
 TR       |                 2 |                     4
(4 rows)
```

**Live test**

Incorrect query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9774a/2

Correct query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9774a/1

Comment: How's your query now? Are you able to solve it little by little? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  

No, MySql doesn't support CTE-style queries. So I would go with the other suggestion. Someone else has also suggested the same solution in an other post, but I was trying to avoid using these 'sub-query' left-joins as the joining tables themselve contain a huge amount of data which I thought can slow down the query execution. But it seems I don't have any other choice for now.  

Another thing, how would we use 'with rollup' in this situation?

Comment: I don't use ROLLUP that much, most of reports I'm making is out the box functionality, e.g. Crystal Report, it perfectly facilitates things like results rollup, though I make sure to pass aggregated results to CR already, and just delegate rollup to CR, so CR won't be bogged down with big data. Try to simulate ROLLUP in your MySQL Browser or http://sqlfiddle.com with small data. Do it in small data, analyze the behavior. I don't know exactly what are the nuances of ROLLUP :-)

Answer (score 0):

I question your distinct usage here - the way it is written it will return 1 or 0. Which means a count distinct will only ever return 0, 1 or 2.

I assume you have unique ID columns in each of your tables.  You can change the case to return the ID value, then count distinct that.  If your join returns multiple of the same row from your pd_markings table, a distinct count on the ID will return, well, only the distinct count of rows.

Comment: Yeah, thats true about the 1 or 0 returning value. Thats the desired result actualy, as one-to-one relationship tables will only have either 1 or 0 rows against any files.id, so if I don't use 'Distinct' then the resulting value is wrong (i guess because of the other tables which are returning more then one row against same file.id)
No, unfortunately, my tables don't have their own unique ID columns except the 'files' table.